# Horizontal Slider - move with grabbing trigger link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a horizontal gallery with links but the issue is that when I want to move elements in the gallery on mousedown and mousemove but then on mouseup you are relocated (after end of the whole click event) how can I solve this? Any Ideas ?

DEMO: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jn4a58e/)

JS

```
(function() {
  var x,
    y,
    top,
    left,
    down;

  $("ul").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    down = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    left = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $(this).addClass("grabbing");
  });

  $("ul a").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("ul").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (down) {
      var newX = e.pageX;
      var newY = e.pageY;
      $("ul").scrollLeft(left - newX + x);
    }
  });

  $("ul").mouseup(function(e) {
    down = false;
    $(this).removeClass("grabbing");
  });
})();
```

Comment: Do you want the individual slides to be clickable? The problem is that you have anchors and the click will trigger the default behavior of the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding another div as a link, and treating the pictures as grabable stuff.

But you can do something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var x,
    y,
    top,
    left,
    down;

  $("ul").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    down = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    left = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $(this).addClass("grabbing");
  });

  $("a").mouseup(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('test');
  });

  $("ul").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (down) {
      var newX = e.pageX;
      var newY = e.pageY;
      $("ul").scrollLeft(left - newX + x);
    }
  });

  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
 $("a").mouseup(function(e) {
    down = false;
    $(this).removeClass("grabbing");
     var newerX = e.pageX;
     
     if(newerX !== x) { // Instead of x you can use newX
       
     // Do nothing with the click if there is scrolled
       
     } else {
       
       // Go to link anyway
      window.location = this.href;
       
     }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Yes that is true with another div. Thank you for your input Sythe

Answer (score 1):

You also can use something like:
https://jsfiddle.net/4jn4a58e/7/

```js
(function() {
  var x,
    y,
    top,
    left,
    down,
    moved;

  $("ul").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   moved = false;
    down = true;
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    left = $(this).scrollLeft();
    $(this).addClass("grabbing");
  });

  $("ul a").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("ul").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (down) {
    moved = true;
      var newX = e.pageX;
      var newY = e.pageY;
      $("ul").scrollLeft(left - newX + x);
    }
  });

  $("ul").mouseup(function(e) {
     down = false;
     $(this).removeClass("grabbing");
  });
  
  $("ul a").click(function(e) {
    if (moved) {
     e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
ul {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: grab;
  &.grabbing {
    cursor: grabbing;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    @for $i from 2 through 6 {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        left: (155px * $i) - 155;
        background: #123123 * $i;
      }
    }
    a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="google.com"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```